# Adding widgets to particular div using knockout and jquery templates

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js

Is it possible for a template to check an attribute of an element it is being bound to and then decide if it should actually been bound to it?

The idea is that I would have a number of `div`s and the template would bind to each `div` n number of times depending on the id of the div and the id in the data.

```html
<div id="col1" class="col" data-bind="template: 'widgetsTemplate'">  
</div>

<div id="col2" class="col" data-bind="template: 'widgetsTemplate'">    
</div>

@*<div data-bind="template: 'widgetsTemplate'" />*@
<script id="widgetsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div>
    {{each(index,widget) widgets}}
        {{if widget.col == cols[index].id}} 
            <div>${widget.name}</div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

Corresponding JS:

```
var cols = $('.col'); 
function widget(name, col) {
    return {
        name: ko.observable(name),
        col: ko.observable(col)
    };
}
var viewModel = {
    widgets: ko.observableArray(
    [new widget("Widget 1", col1),
    new widget("Widget 2", col2)])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This is as far as I got with this idea but I don't seem to be able to progress.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd like to have 1 list with widgets, and have the templates figure out which widgets they need to use? Couldn't you, for example, bind an array of strings to your templates. Then each string would represent a widget name, and for each string you'd render a div. Then have jquery look up the div's which have the "widget" attribute(for example) and bind the proper widget to it(assuming these widgets are jquery plugins). Didn't post it as an answer because I'm a little unsure what the question is. Because templates will only be bound to an element IF there is a data-bind:" template" attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can  dynamically change which template to bind by looking a result of a function. May be you can change the way of implementing your idea.

In the example code you decide inside the template whatever you want to render. You can decide at top level and choose which template to bind by examining the data. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ujr4z/).

Comment: Thanks guys - I found this based on what you said which does the trick nicely http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wvDTA/